# Closed form for the recursion $\displaystyle u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} u_ku_{n-1-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I was completing a computer science problem when the following recursion popped up:

> $u_0=1$
>
> $\displaystyle u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} u_ku_{n-1-k}$

Is there a closed form for this recursion ?

I can't find anything on my own.

Comment: Was the starting point $u_0 = 1$? You use $u_0$ in the recurrence.

Comment: Should $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}$ be $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}$?

Comment: And, just to mention it: [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: @DanielFischer it's fixed now. You should make it an answer.

Comment: Given that these are indeed Catalan numbers, this is almost certainly a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a closed form for this [famous sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):

$$u_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}.$$